# Java 1.3.1, compiler errors

Tags: java

I'm using a new work computer that has an old sdk, Java 1.3.1, on it and wanted to see if I could do some class homework on it.  I have this file from our professor and it works on his machine in class, and I am getting compiler errors when I run it.  I checked the Java help files onlines and it looks like Collections have been supported prior to 1.3.1 so I am not sure why I am getting these errors.  Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class WriteFile
{ 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        if(args.length == 0) {
            args = new String[] { ".." }; 
        }
        List<String> nextDir = new ArrayList<String>();
        nextDir.add(args[0]); 
        try 
        { 

                while(nextDir.size() > 0) 
                { 
                    File pathName = new File(nextDir.get(0)); 
                    String[] fileNames = pathName.list(); 

                    for(int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) 
                    { 
                        File f = new File(pathName.getPath(), fileNames[i]); 
                            if (f.isDirectory()) 
                            { 
                                System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath()); 
                        nextDir.add(f.getPath()); 
                        } 
                        } 
                nextDir.remove(0); 
                } 
        } 
            catch(IOException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
    } 
}
```

Errors:
'(' or ']' on line 12 which to me doesn't look like an error.
Then a lot of cannot resolve symbol for List, String, nextDir on line 12, etc.

I figured it's either something super obvious, or something wrong with my work configuration.  Thanks.

Comment: Can't you sneak a Java 6 JDK in?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generics is only supported from java 1.5+

Use regular lists like

```
List nextDir = new ArrayList();
```

That should work hopefully

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe generics (i.e.  `List<String>`) were supported prior to Java 5.