# Removing warning messages on IntelliJ IDEA while building Java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition for the first time and using Maven to set up a TDD environment. The code that I am trying to test and the warning messages I had encountered along with the project structure are provided below.

### Project Structure:

[image]

### Code:

```
package miscellaneous;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class TestHello {

    // Methods to be tested.....
    private int Add1Plus1(int i, int j) {
        return (i + j);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd1Plus1() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(2, Add1Plus1(1, 1));
    }
}
```

### Configuration details:

- **Java compiler:** 1.8.0_45
- **Maven Version:** 3.0.5
- **Path to Maven user-settings file:** /home/sandeep/Desktop/MyDocs/repos/git-repos/public/MavenCodeBase/settings.xml
- **Path to Maven local repository:** /home/sandeep/Desktop/MyDocs/repos/maven-repos
- **pom.xml:** http://pastebin.com/462Uytad

### Warning messages:

```
Warning:java: source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
Warning:java: target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
Warning:java: To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
```

### Question:

What is causing these messages and what would be a good/recommended way to fix these warning messages?

Comment: Your pom does not show any configuration of the compiler plugin, try setting -[source and -target](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) in your pom.xml

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Check java version in your **pom.xml**([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723533/modify-pom-xml-to-include-jdk-compiler-version) you can find how to do it).
Also check java version in **Project Structure**. And the last what you can do - check compiler version e.g.

[image]

Comment: Ok. So, if I have understood correctly, there is a difference between `File -> Project Structure --> Project(Setting Project SDK to above 1.5)` and `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment, Compiler -> Java Compiler` and setting Target bytecode version to above 1.5.

Comment: Yes, the java sdk in all listed above setting must be the same!

Comment: The fact that they have to be always the same, but aren't located in the same place, is one of my least favorite features of IntelliJ.

Comment: Is there a configuration setting somewhere, which would always make this get set to a sensible value (i.e. according to selected JDK) when creating a new IntelliJ IDEA project?

Answer (score 72):

I did all of the above and still had one instance of the warning:

```
Warning:java: source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
```

I went into my **project_name.iml** file and replaced the following tag:

```
<component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_5" inherit-compiler-output="false">
```

with:

```
<component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_8" inherit-compiler-output="false">
```

And voila, no more error message. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: thank you. Was having the same problem. This solved it!

Comment: Worked for me too. Need to make the change in the [Answer by Schermann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30691731/642706) plus this Answer here too.

Comment: My .iml file doesn't have that. It instead looks like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4" />

Comment: @emirhosseini It depends on how you set up your project. You may not have that tag in your .iml file. If not see suggestions above. :) Good luck

Answer (score 18):

If the project with Maven, check *pom.xml* file for source and target:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And in case of Gradle - check *build.gradle* for:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case none of the above solution worked. But changing language level in project structure did.

File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Modules -> under "sources" tab change language level to some upper version.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

If you have Maven project, open **pom.xml** file and add following code inside your project root:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue in Gradle project of Java.

In build.gradle file, there was a warning that the assignment was not used. I removed the `sourceCompatibility = 1.5` line in build.gradle file and all the warning messages disappeared.

[image: value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release]

Answer (score 2):

The real reason is that, your module target jdk version is not same with the IDE.
One move to solve this problem: Preferences->Build,Execution,Deployment->Compiler->Java Compiler->Javac Options: uncheck **Use compiler from module target JDK when possible**
Also, others answer about the pom is correct too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

OR

```
<project>
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```