# Setting up Java version while running a maven build

Tags: java, version

I am using Java 1.8(which is set in all env variables. Also I dont not have any other version installed.)

Still when I am doing a maven build on a project, its giving me the below error:
"diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)"

Please suggest.

Comment: Maven finds the java version from JAVA_HOME parameter.
You can also go to `mvn` (non-windows)/ `mvn.bat` (windows) and set the java version explicitly. Can you check what are the values set for both of these?

Comment: mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T22:59:23+05:30)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.8.0_73, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre

Comment: Can you include `maven-compiler-plugin`? 
Kindly refer to [http://stackoverflow.com/a/16723563/1925997](answer) on how to include it in pom.xml. 
You can also, specify the properties <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source> and <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>.
This should fix the issue.

Comment: That's right..It did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing this:

```
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Where maven.compiler.source and target is 1.8