# Jsp 's are compiled into older java version

Tags: java, jsp, compilation, java-8, websphere

At the moment i'm migrating an application to java 8. This application id deployes on WAS 8.5.5.9 (Full profile). The application is working fine. Java 8 code is also working. So sar so good.  But when I take a closer look to the compiled jsp's I see that they are compiled into java 6. Anyone who knows whats the problem and how I can solve this?

Comment: You need to look at your build file. What build tool do you use maven/gradle/ant?

Comment: Using maven. The "Normal" java files are java 8.@randominstanceOfLivingThing

Comment: Most likely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723533/how-do-you-specify-the-java-compiler-version-in-a-pom-xml-file will solve your problem.

Comment: You have  `<target>1.6</target>` in your pom.xml file. Please confirm.

Comment: Seems like WAS bug: [PI66266: JSP ENGINE CANNOT COMPILE WITH JAVA V8](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI66266&myns=swgws&mynp=OCSSEQTP&mync=R&cm_sp=swgws-_-OCSSEQTP-_-R)