# Not able maven build "strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5 in eclipse while maven build"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

i am getting  strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5 (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch) in eclipse while run as->maven build. I am using java 8 and OS is ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What is the jdk version mentioned in your pom.xml? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16723563/3603806

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `maven-compiler-plugin` with java version 1.8.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

then go to project property > java compiler select jdk version 1.8.
[image]